# Knockout json data showing too many rows

Tags: json, knockout.js

I have a knockout view model which consists of an observableArray of objects.

I am usig this json data to populate the array

This JSON structure is a simplified version of my real structure. In that, I want to give several attributes to one item, for example to control whether a form input is enabled or not: `{"name":"George", "input_disabled":"true", "input_maxlength":"50}` etc

```js
function listItem(id, name, address) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.address = ko.observable(address);
}
function vModel(data) {
 var self = this;
 self.listArray = ko.observableArray();
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
   self.listArray.push(new listItem(val.id, val.name, val.address));
  });
 return {
  listArray : self.listArray
 }
}

var jsondata = [
{"id":"1"}, {"name":"George"}, {"age": "35"}, {"occupation": "Architect"}, {"address":"NY"},
{"id":"2"}, {"name":"Jerry"}, {"age": "35"}, {"occupation": "Comedian"}, {"address":"Brooklyn"},
{"id":"3"}, {"name":"Elaine"}, {"age": "35"}, {"occupation": "Publisher"}, {"address":"Manhattan"}
];

ko.applyBindings(new vModel(jsondata));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: listArray()">
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td data-bind="text: address"></td>      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I populate the array with the included JSON, the foreach loop prints out too many rows. As per the knockout documentation, the foreach loop duplicates the html elements for each item in the array.

But the question is, is there any way possible for me to get this JSON working with knockout? Or do I have to change the JSON similar to: `var jsondata = [[{"id":"1"}, {"name":"George"}]]` etc

Comment: you need an array of single object for each row like `var jsondata = [{ "id": "1", "name": "George", "age": "35", "occupation": "Architect", "address": "NY" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Jerry", "age": "35", "occupation": "Comedian", "address": "Brooklyn" } ]`

Comment: Thank you for this, I will change the incoming JSON.

Comment: If you *can*, you should definitely change the data format server side. If you can't, you can cut up the array in sections of 5 key value pairs and merge those using `Object.assign`. For example, in an ugly one-liner: `jsondata.reduce((res, kvp, i) => (i % 5 ? Object.assign(res[res.length - 1], kvp) : res.push(kvp), res), [])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout `foreach` binds to each element in the array. By defining the json structure like you did, you would have 15 rows in the table. You also have no way of knowing what `id` corresponds to what `name`.

I've changed your JSON structure as follows:

```
[{ "id": "1", "name": "George", "age": "35", "occupation": "Architect", 
"address": "NY" },
{ "id": "2", "name": "Jerry", "age": "35", "occupation": 
"Comedian", "address": "Brooklyn" },
{"id":"3", "name":"Elaine", "age": "35", "occupation": "Publisher", 
"address":"Manhattan"}]
```

```js
function listItem(id, name, address) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.address = ko.observable(address);
}
function vModel(data) {
 var self = this;
 self.listArray = ko.observableArray();
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
   self.listArray.push(new listItem(val.id, val.name, val.address));
  });
 return {
  listArray : self.listArray
 }
}

var jsondata = 
[{ "id": "1", "name": "George", "age": "35", "occupation": "Architect", "address": "NY" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Jerry", "age": "35", "occupation": "Comedian", "address": "Brooklyn" },
{"id":"3", "name":"Elaine", "age": "35", "occupation": "Publisher", "address":"Manhattan"}
];

ko.applyBindings(new vModel(jsondata));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: listArray()">
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td data-bind="text: address"></td>      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I thought I needed to change my json into.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

Going a bit deeper: if I wanted to build a form based on that data, how would I go about it?

Let's say I wanted to show each row as part of the form. Then the JSON data would also be used to control the input element. For example: I want to define in my JSON that "id" is a hidden field and "name" is read only. This would be applied differently to each set of data, based on the JSON.

```
<table class="table">
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="name" readonly="readonly" value="George" /></td></tr>
</table>
<table class="table">
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="name" disabled="disabled" value="Jerry" /></td></tr>
</table>
<table class="table">
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="name" size="75" value="Elaine" /></td></tr>
</table>
```